# Splash Screen not working with Deep links and when launched from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-12, android-deep-link, android-splashscreen

When I launch my app from launcher screen the Splash Screen works fine
[image]

but when I launch my app via deep link, the logo animation is not triggered and also the code in the associated SpalshScreen.OnExitAnimationListener object is not called
[image]

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name=".main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="prateekgupta.pythonanywhere.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**theme.xml**

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/logo_bg</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_logo_animation</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">2000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MainTheme</item>
    </style>
```

**MainActivity**

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);

splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener(splashScreenViewProvider -> {
            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f);
            translateAnimation.setDuration(1000L);
            translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    splashScreenViewProvider.remove();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            // Starting exit animation of SplashScreen
            splashScreenViewProvider.getView().startAnimation(translateAnimation);
        });
```

Is I'm missing something, because the same issue also occurs when I launch my app in my physical device with Android 12 from Android Studio.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am seeing the same behavior in my app running the latest API 33.  I don't ever recall seeing this behavior before.  Its only happening on Android, iOS works just fine.  If the app opened quickly and went right to the deep link I wouldn't mind too much, but its actually taking about 4 to 5 seconds and during that time instead of seeing a splash screen, all the user sees is a blank screen then the deeplink page finally appears.  but the delay is way too long to not be displaying something to the user.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/logo_bg</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_logo_animation</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">2000</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MainTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBehavior">icon_preferred</item>
</style>
```

Adding this line
**<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBehavior">icon_preferred</item>** makes the icon display correctly even when executing deep links.

Comment: This works, but `android:windowSplashScreenBehavior` seems to be supported only from API 33.
Any solution for API 31-32?